# Assistance needed with regular expressions

Tags: regex

The HTTP messages are listed below right after the questions.

1. I need a regular expression that finds the HTTP status codes within both messages.
2. Another one that finds the name of the requesting user in both messages.
3. A last one that finds the time stamp within both messages.

```
127.0.0.1 - Johny [17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif  
HTTP/1.0" 200 2326

127.0.0.1 - debbie7 [19/Dec/2010:11:11:02 -0700] "GET /apache_pbs.gif   
HTTP/1.0" 404 2336
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Vague title will not help future visitors to the site with the same problem.

Comment: Nothing really. I'm a beginner to Regex (Sorry)..

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

You can pull the values {username, date, and http code} in one pass using this regex:

`^.*?-\s(\S*)\s+\[([^\]]*)\]\s"[^"]*"\s(\d+)\s\d+`

[image]

## Groups

Group 0 gets the entire line, while the other groups will individually get the respective matches.

1. gets the username
2. gets the date stamp
3. gets the http status code

## PHP Code Example:

You didn't select a language so I present a php example to show how the regex works

Given input string, complete with link break in the middle of the message area

```
127.0.0.1 - Johny [17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif 
HTTP/1.0" 200 2326

127.0.0.1 - debbie7 [19/Dec/2010:11:11:02 -0700] "GET /apache_pbs.gif 
HTTP/1.0" 404 2336
```

Code Example

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^.*?-\s(\S*)\s+\[([^\]]*)\]\s"[^"]*"\s(\d+)\s\d+/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 127.0.0.1 - Johny [17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif 
HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
            [1] => 127.0.0.1 - debbie7 [19/Dec/2010:11:11:02 -0700] "GET /apache_pbs.gif 
HTTP/1.0" 404 2336
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Johny
            [1] => debbie7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700
            [1] => 19/Dec/2010:11:11:02 -0700
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 404
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful via a PHP perspective.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status:

```
(?<=HTTP/1.0" )\d+
```

Requesting user (works for any ip address):

```
(?<=(\d\d?\d?\.){3}\d\d?\d? - )\w+(?= \[)
```

Timestamp:

```
(?<=\[).*(?=\])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this Regex to achieve this:

```
^.* (\w*) \[([^\]]*)] \"[\w.\/ ]*\" ([\d]+)
```

**Input:**

```
127.0.0.1 - Johny [17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif  
HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

**Output:**

```
Group 1: Johny
Group 2: 17/Dec/2010:17:15:16 -0700
Group 3: 200
```

You can test the Regex [here](http://regexr.com?356p6).

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
!([a-zA-Z]+) \W+          
 (.* -) [\w\W]+
 HTTP/1.0" \ ([\d]+)
!x

$1 -> username
$2 -> timestamp
$3 -> status
```